# How to share synced Realm, write to and read from it from different Swift classes / ViewModels / Views?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, combine

I am trying to split all my business logic into various classes (Managers, e.g. a `RealmManager`, ...) and accessing them through ViewModel classes to display the UI. Data between classes is kept up to date using Combine. Specifically, I want to display a live `User` object in the UI that is on a synced realm, managed by some separate class from the ViewModel.

I have tried various things but keep running into thread related issues with the realm reference and trying to write / read from it. Below I get the crash:

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread.'*

**How can I separate the creation of a (synced) realm and its management of changing subscriptions, write to it from different classes and read from it in the UI?**

---

The code I have is something like this:
(with printing stuff I found out that at least the `User` object arrives at the ViewModel, but reading it makes the app crash)

```swift
public class RealmManager: NSObject {
    static var shared: RealmManager = RealmManager()
    var realm: Realm?
    var realmUserID: String?

    func setupRealm(authToken: String) async throws {
        guard let user = await getRealmUser() else { // this loads the realm user
            print("couldn't get realm user")
        }
        self.realmUserID = user.id
        
        // setup sync subscriptions & realm
        guard let realm = self.setupRealmSubscriptions(user: user) else { // this loads the realm
            print("couldn't add subs / setup realm")
        }
        // this function does this using Realm(configuration: flexSyncConfig)
        self.realm = realm


        AccountManager.shared.loadOwnUser()
    }
}
```

(`setupRealm()` is called externally after some authentication logic)

```swift
public class AccountManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    static var shared: AccountManager = AccountManager()

    @Published var ownUser: User?

    func loadOwnUser() {
        guard let realmUserId = RealmManager.shared.realmUserId else {
            print("AccountManager setup failed")
        }
        let ownUser = User(_id: realmUserId) // user object that will be displayed in UI, see struct below
            do {
                try realm.write {
                    realm.add(ownUser)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.ownUser = ownUser
                }
            } catch {
                print("oups!")
            }
    }
}
```

Then in my ViewModel I am using combine to see when a realm `User` object is ready:

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    @Published var ownUser: User?

    init() {
        loadUser()
    }

    func loadUser() {
        RealmManager.shared.$ownUser
            .sink { completion in print("Completed with \(completion)")
                } receiveValue: { [weak self] ownUser in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.ownUser = ownUser
                    }
                }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

and finally in my view:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel // passed from a view controller that this TestView lives in
    
    var body: some View {
        if let ownUser = viewModel.ownUser {
            Text(ownUser._id)
        }
    }
}
}
```

User struct:

```swift
class User: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id = UUID().uuidString
    convenience init(_id: String? = nil) {
        self.init()
        if let _id = _id {
            self._id = _id
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: I have heard that storing references to realms is not recommended, but how would I efficiently implement this in my case with complex subscriptions needed on a synced realm that has to be accessed in various places of my app?

Comment: That's quite a bit of code for us to parse through and the actual issue is not really clear. Also, you've got a smattering of `DispatchQueue.main.async` and it's not clear what that's for. I think you're going down the right path; having a singleton to work with Realm is common. We, for example, had a singleton `gGetRealm` (we use gXXX for global functions - singletons). So when we want to access it `let realm = gGetRealm()`. Can you narrow the issue to a specific line(s) of code? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)